# Routing in SAPUI5: How to implement passing of URL? Model data not initialy loaded

Tags: url-routing, sapui5

My goal is to write a SAPUI5 Fiori app with routing support. One mail goal is to have passable URLs. For example in an E-Mail like "please approve this: *link*". The *link* is an URL matched by my rounting config, e.g.`index.html#/applicants/8`.

I use a typical sap.m.SplitApp kind of application. Clicking a list item in masterview changes the URL to `index.html#/applicants/[id of entry in JSON]`. I can click on the list, my defined routes are getting matched and the apps loads the (applicant) data as expected.

However, and here comes my question, this doeas not work when using an URL directly, say pasting `[my url]/index.html#/applicants/8` into my browser. The app is launched but no detail data is loaded. I have to click on another list item again to get the data.

Actually, the controller is called when passing the URL, but it seems the model is not initiated and undefined. My JSON model is bound in the `createContent` function of my `Component.js`

// Update 2015-05-14
The problems seems to be around the `getData()` function. I have the model, it has the entries, but `getData()` returns undefined for the first time my app is loaded. I recently read `getData()` is deprecated. How should I improve my coding below?

```
// Component.js
ui5testing.Component.prototype.createContent = function(){
  // create root view
  var oView = sap.ui.view({
    id : "app",
    viewName : "ui5testing.view.Main",
    type : "JS",
    viewData : {
        component : this
    }
  var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel("model/mock_applicants.json");
  oView.setModel(oModel);
  [...]
  return oView;
});
// Master controller
handleApplicantSelect : function (evt) {
    var oHashChanger = sap.ui.core.routing.HashChanger.getInstance();
    var context  = evt.getParameter("listItem").getBindingContext();
    var path = context.getPath();
    var model = this.getView().getModel();
    var item =  model.getProperty(path);
    oHashChanger.setHash("applicants/" + item.id);
},

// Detail controller
onInit: function() {
    this.router = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
    this.router.attachRoutePatternMatched(this._handleRouteMatched, this);
},

_handleRouteMatched : function(evt){        
    var objectId = evt.getParameter("arguments").id;
    var model = this.getView().getModel();
    var data = model.getData()["applicants"];
    var pathId;

    if (data) {
        for (var i = 0; data.length; i++) {
            if ( objectId == data[i].id ) {
                pathId = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        var sPath = "/applicants/" + pathId;

        var context = new sap.ui.model.Context(model, sPath)
        this.getView().setBindingContext(context);              
    }
},
```

Comment: is createContent called? How and where do you set the model? this.getView().getModel(); doesn't sound like a good idea when the model is not already attached to the particular view BEFORE.

Comment: Sorry, I got it fixed already. See update.

Comment: Sorry again, after a refactor the issue emerged again. The model is set in the Compoent.js createContent(). Set to the Main root view.

Comment: Havent seen a code that says router.navTo. You are probably just trying to change the hash. Please consider using router. Else try and send me the code. I will be able to solve it.

Comment: @NareshKumarDevalapally Thank you for your hint about using the router. The code above is outdated, I recently did what you recommended and switched to router.navTo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've figured out that getData() returns undefined for the first time, which means the model data is still not yet loaded. So you can make use of attachRequestCompleted method of the model & fire an event from the component & listen to that event in the detail controller to ensure the routerPatternMatched() gets executed only after the data is loaded.

//Component.js

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel("model/mock_applicants.json");

oModel.attachRequestCompleted(jQuery.proxy(function(){
   this.fireEvent("MockDataLoaded"); // fireEvent through component
},this));

oView.setModel(oModel);
```

//Detail controller

```
onInit : function(){

this.router = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);  

var oComponent = this.getOwnerComponent();

oComponent.attachEvent("MockDataLoaded",jQuery.proxy(function(){
   this.router.attachRoutePatternMatched(this._handleRouteMatched, this);
},this));

}
```

Or the simplest & but the dirty way would be to make an synchronous request instead of an async request to load data.

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();

oModel.loadData(""model/mock_applicants.json",{bAsync:false});

oView.setModel(oModel);
```

Comment: Very helpfull answer, thank you! I admid, that I found a way using `attachRequestCompleted` by myself. However, your solution looks clearer. One question: is it possible to use the SAPUI5 `EventBus` instead of `jQuery.proxy()` ?

Comment: you can use EventBus instead of firing Events! The reason for using jQuery.proxy is that, the value of 'this' within the event handler will be different. Give a try removing the jQuery.proxy from the event handler function & try to figure out the value of 'this'.